# I want to reload a datatable using ajax without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to refresh table after every 3 seconds. I will appreciate your help. am using the same page to add new records to the database . it does not make any logic for the to refresh the page to view the records they have just saved.

```
var table = $(".customer-table").dataTable({
            "sort": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "{{url('/brah/brah')}}",
                "contentType": "application/json",
                "type": "GET",
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "created_at"},
                {
                    "data": null,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var details = row.first_name + " " + row.last_name;
                        return details;
                    }
}

            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `dataTable` with `DataTable`. 
And then this should be your solution:

```
var table = $(".customer-table").DataTable({}); /* fill in your attributes */
setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 3000 );
```

https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: th above method it has this error : add:530 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined
    at add:530

Comment: I’m wondering about your spelling of `dataTable`. Do you use this plugin: https://datatables.net/?

Comment: var table = $(".customer-table").DataTable({});

Comment: ST you have to make your answer a real answer for him to mark it solved